# xamarin.forms webview.focused event raised on Android, but not on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, webview

I'm using a Xamarin.Forms grid application to show a couple of html elements as WebViews in the cells of the grid CardGrid:

```
    private async void CreateCardView()
    {
        CardGrid.Children.Clear();

        // idx over all count elements of html snippets
        for (idx = 0; idx < count; idx++)
        {
            string html = AuthoringCard(idx);
            RenderingCard(html, idx);
        }
    }
```

AuthoringCard() creates the html code snippet.

RenderingCard() creates the WebView inside the grid cell.

```
    private void RenderingCard(string htmlCard, int index)
    {
        int CardWidth = 300;
        int CardHeight = 150;
        int CardNoHorizontally = 3;

        WebView uiCard = new WebView();
        uiCard.HeightRequest = CardHeight - 5;
        uiCard.WidthRequest= CardWidth - 5;
        uiCard.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;
        uiCard.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
        uiCard.Margin = new Thickness(0);
        uiCard.AutomationId = index.ToString();
        uiCard.Focused += Card_Tapped;
        uiCard.InputTransparent = false;

        var htmlSource1 = new HtmlWebViewSource
        {
            Html = htmlCard,
        };
        uiCard.Source = htmlSource1;

        CardGrid.Children.Add(uiCard);

        int row = (int)Math.Floor((double)(index / CardNoHorizontally));
        int column = index - (row * CardNoHorizontally);

        Grid.SetRow(uiCard, row);
        Grid.SetColumn(uiCard, column);
    }
```

I want to catch the Focused event, when the user it tapping on the card (WebView) and using the AutomationId to get the index of the card (html code snippet):

```
    private void Card_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebView card = (WebView)sender;

        int index = Convert.ToInt16(card.AutomationId));
    }
```

This works fine with Android. Under iOS the event is never raised. Any idea for a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause:**

the property `Focus` in Forms correspond method that we called [becomeFirstResponder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextview/1807130-becomefirstresponder?language=occ) in native iOS platform.Unfortunately,UIWebView and WKwebview do not support the method `becomeFirstResponder`.This method is only available in some 'input-controls' Such as UITextField and UITextView(Entry in Forms).So even if you set the event on a `webview`.It will not work in iOS.

**Workaround:**

You can add a `TapGestureRecognizer` on the webview.And you have to implement it by using CustomRenderer.Because it will create conflict if you add TapGestureRecognizer in forms.
Refer to the following code.

> in Forms

```
public MainPage()
{
 if (Device.RuntimePlatform == "iOS")
   {

      MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object,string>(this,"webview_click", (sender,arg)=> {

     // int index = Convert.ToInt16(arg));

     });
   }
}
```

> in iOS

```
using System;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using xxx;
using xxx.iOS;
using ObjCRuntime;
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView),typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
  public class MyWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer, IUIGestureRecognizerDelegate
  {

    public bool isFirstLoad = true;

    public MyWebViewRenderer()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e != null)
        {
            UITapGestureRecognizer tap = new UITapGestureRecognizer(this, new Selector("Tap_Handle:"));
            tap.WeakDelegate = this;
            this.AddGestureRecognizer(tap);
        }

    }

    [Export("gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:")]
    public bool ShouldRecognizeSimultaneously(UIGestureRecognizer gestureRecognizer, UIGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer)
    {
        return true;
    }

    [Export("Tap_Handle:")]
    void Tap_Handle(UITapGestureRecognizer tap)
    {
        if(isFirstLoad)
        {
            isFirstLoad = false;
            MessagingCenter.Send<Object,string>(this, "webview_click",Element.AutomationId);
        }
    }

  }
}
```